# I need to get the value in my variables to my parameter

Tags: ios, swift

The values in my variables are inside their own functions and I don't know how to get them out

I have a parameter

`let parameters = ["attendance": "3", "reason": (reason + " " + otherReasonText), "from": dateFrom, "to": dateTo]`

this parameter is within the class `ViewController` only

1. reason

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){ 
    let reason = reasonPicker[row]
}
```

2. otherReasonText //which is inside an IBAction of a button

   `let otherReasonText: String = leaveTextView.text!`
3. dateFrom/dateTo //this two has the same purpose but just two different datepickers

```
@IBAction func FromDatePicker(_ sender: Any) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let dateFrom = dateFormatter.string(from: datepickerFrom.date)
        
    print(dateFrom)
}
```

I just need these variables to go into the parameter because I will send that parameter as a POST request but the i don't know how to get the variables into the parameter.

Comment: why you don't save variables outside of the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value from the pickerview, datepicker and text from textview wherever you want like this.

```
func callAPI() {
    let reason = reasonPicker[reasonPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let otherReasonText = leaveTextView.text!
    let dateFrom = fromDatePicker.date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let dateFrom = dateFormatter.string(from: datepickerFrom.date)
    let dateTo = dateFormatter.string(from: datepickerTo.date)
    let parameters = ["attendance": "3", "reason": (reason + " " + otherReasonText), "from": dateFrom, "to": dateTo]
    //call api
}
```

Comment: the parameters is inside an IBAction function `do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }`

with the callAPI() parameter couldnt get the other variables

Comment: @Olufsen What do you mean by _"couldnt get the other variables"_?

Comment: Nvm haha im fine now thank you I just placed your code inside the function where parameters is located thanks